# Find coefficients of the polynomial $1-(1-x)(1-2x)\dotsb (1-nx)$

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

As in the title I'm finding the coefficients $a_k$ (coefficient of $k$th term) of the following polynomial

$$p(x)=1-\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1-kx)$$

As one clearly sees $a_0=0$ and, with a bit of computation that $a_1=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.
For $a_2$ the question is more complicated, I think the answer is $$a_2=\frac{1}{2} \sum_2^nk^2(k-1)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sum_2^nk^3 -\sum_2^n k^2\right)$$

---

In genearl 
I can write (tell me if it's wrong or there is a more friendly way to write)

$$a_k=(-1)^{k+1}\sum_{\substack{I \subseteq \{1,\dotsb,n\} \\ |I|=k}}\prod_{i \in I}i $$

The questions are:

1. Can I make this **more explicit** and **simpler** like the cases $a_1, a_2$?
2. Can I write $a_k$ as **sums** of power of the first $n$ integers?

Comment: Why not look at $\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1-kx)$?

Comment: Yes the coefficient $c_k$ of $\prod_{k=1}^n (x-k)$ is $\displaystyle c_k=(-1)^{n-k}\sum_{\substack{I \subseteq \{1,\dotsb,n\} \\ |I|=k}}\prod_{i \in I}i$. You can't simplify much more, see [Falling_and_rising_factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)

Comment: Stirling numbers.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown are they what I'm looking for to simplify that sum of products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Consider the polynomial

$$P_n(x) = \prod_{k=1}^{n} (1+kx) := \sum_{j=0}^{n}a_j(n)x^j$$
Accounting the convention that $a_{j}(n) =0 $ if $j>n$ and notice this does not affect any of $P_n(x)'s$.

Then

> $$\boxed{ 1-P_n(-x)=1-(1-x)(1-2x)\dotsb (1-nx)} $$
>   Therefore it suffices to find $a_j(n)$ $j= 0,1\cdots ,n$

On the other hand, we have 
$$ P_{n+1}(x) = \prod_{k=1}^{n+1} (1+kx) =  P_n(x)+(n+1)P_n(x)x := \sum_{j=0}^{n}a_j(n+1)x^j$$
But it easy to check that

$$ P_n(x)+(n+1)P_n(x)x = 1+(n+1)a_n(n)x^{n+1}+ \sum_{j=1}^{n}[a_j(n)+(n+1)a_{j-1}(n)]x^j $$
By identification we get $a_{n+1}(n+1)=(n+1)a_{n}(n)$, $a_0(n)=1$ and

$$ a_{j}(n+1)=a_j(n)+(n+1)a_{j-1}(n)~~\text{for}~~j= 1\cdots ,n$$

> It is easy to see that $a_0(n)=1$, $a_1(n)=\binom{n+1}{2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $a_{n}(n) =n!$

Also, $\text{for}~~j= 1,\cdots ,n$
$$ a_{j}(n+1)-a_j(n)= (n+1)a_{j-1}(n)~$$

which leads to 
$$a_{j}(n+1)-a_j(0) = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}a_{j}(k)-a_j(k-1) =\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k a_{j-1}(k)   $$

Whence, $\text{for}~~j= 1,\cdots ,n$

$$a_{j}(n+1) = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k a_{j-1}(k)$$

Comment: "But it easy to check that...", In LHS there is a $x^{n+1}$ term which is not in RHS. I'm unsure about it in general, why is it true?

Comment: is that ok for you now?

Comment: Yes now is clear, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think some light might be cast on this question *via* the use of [***elementary symmetric functions***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial).  Given $m$ indeterminates $z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m$ we define, for $0 \le k \le m$, the $k$-th such function $\sigma_k(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m)$ as follows:

$\sigma_0(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m) = 1; \tag 1$

$\sigma_1(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m) = z_1 + z_2 + \ldots + z_m = \sum_1^m z_i; \tag 2$

$\sigma_2(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m)$
$= z_1z_2 + z_1z_3 + \ldots + z_2z_3 + z_2z_4 + \ldots + z_{m - 1}z_m = \sum_{i, j = 1,\; i < j}^m z_iz_j; \tag 3$

$\sigma_3(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m)$
$= z_1z_2z_3 + z_1z_2z_4 + \ldots + z_2z_3z_4 + z_2z_4z_5 + \ldots + z_{m - 2}z_{m - 1}z_m$
$= \sum_{i, j, k = 1,\; i < j < k}^m z_iz_jz_k, \tag 4$

and so forth, on down to

$\sigma_m(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m) = z_1z_2 \ldots z_m; \tag 5$

we define

$\sigma_k(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m) = 0 \tag 6$

for $k > m$.  In general we may write

$\sigma_k(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m) = \sum_{i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_k = 1}^{i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_k = m}\prod_{i_1 < i_2 < \ldots < i_k} z_{i_j}; \tag 7$

that is, $\sigma_k(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m)$ is the sum of all $k$-fold products of the elements of the set $\{z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m \}$.

Helpful to the present enterprise, I hope and believe, is this identity which the $\sigma_i(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m)$ obey:

$\prod_1^m (1 + z_i) = \sum_0^m \sigma_i(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m); \tag 8$

we present the first few simple cases:

$\prod_1^1 (1 + z_i) = 1 + z_i = \sigma_0(z_1) + \sigma_1(z_1); \tag 9$

$\prod_1^2 (1 + z_i) = (1 + z_1)(1 + z_2)$
$= 1 + z_1 + z_2 + z_1z_2 = \sigma_0(z_1, z_2) + \sigma_1(z_1, z_2) + \sigma_2(z_1, z_2); \tag{10}$

$\prod_1^3 (1 + z_i) = (1 + z_1)(1 + z_2)(1 + z_3)$
$= 1 + z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + z_1z_2 + z_1z_3 + z_2z_3 + z_1z_2z_3$
$= \sigma_0(z_1, z_2, z_3) + \sigma_1(z_1, z_2, z_3) + \sigma_2(z_1, z_2, z_3) + \sigma_3(z_1, z_2, z_3). \tag{11}$

(8) may be proved by a straightforward induction on the number of variables $m$; taking (9)-(11) as base cases, we have, from (8),

$\prod_1^{m + 1} (1 + z_i) = \left (\prod_1^m(1 + z_i) \right )(1 + z_{m + 1}) = (\sum_0^m \sigma_i(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m))(1 + z_{m + 1})$
$= \sum_0^m \sigma_i(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m) + \sum_0^m \sigma_i(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m)z_{m + 1}$
$= \sum_0^m \sigma_i(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m) + \sum_1^{m + 1} \sigma_{i - 1}(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m)z_{m + 1}$
$= \sigma_0(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m) + \sum_1^m \sigma_i(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m)$
$+ \sum_1^m \sigma_{i - 1}(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m)z_{m + 1} + \sigma_m(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m)z_{m + 1}$
$= 1 + \sum_1^m \sigma_i(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m) + \sum_1^m \sigma_{i - 1}(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m)z_{m + 1} + z_1z_2\dots z_{m + 1}$
$= 1 + \sum_1^m (\sigma_i(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m) + \sigma_{i - 1}(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m)z_{m + 1}) + z_1z_2\dots z_{m + 1}. \tag {12}$

Now it is easy to see that

$\sigma_i(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m, z_{m + 1}) = \sigma_i(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m) + \sigma_{i - 1}(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m)z_{m + 1}, \tag{13}$

since the first term on the right is the sum of every distinct $i$-fold product of variables selected from the set $\{z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m \}$, none of which contain $z_{m + 1}$; in the second term, however, each summand contains a factor of $z_{m + 1}$ multiplied by an ${i - 1}$-fold product from $\{z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m \}$; it is easy to see that together these two terms contain every $i$-fold product from $\{z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m, z_{m + 1} \}$, and as such comprise $\sigma_i(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m, z_{m + 1})$, and thus the proof is complete.

Having established (8), we apply it to

$p(x) =  \displaystyle 1 - \prod_1^n (1 - kx); \tag{14}$

taking

$z_k = -kx, \tag{15}$

we find from (8) that

$\displaystyle \prod_1^n (1 - kx) = \sum_0^n \sigma_k(-x, -2x, \ldots, -nx);  \tag{16}$

it may be seen from (7) that $\sigma_k(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m)$ is homogeneous of degree $k$ in the $z_i$; therefore

$ \sigma_k(-x, -2x, \ldots, -nx) = (-1)^kx^k\sigma_k(1, 2 \ldots, n), \tag{17}$

and (16) becomes

$\displaystyle \prod_1^n (1 - kx) = \sum_0^n (-1)^k x^k \sigma_k(1, 2, \ldots, n);  \tag{18}$

furthermore, we see that since

$(-1)^0 x^0 \sigma_0(1, 2, \ldots, n) = 1,  \tag{19}$

the polynomial $p(x)$ may be written

$p(x) = 1 - \displaystyle \prod_1^n (1 - kx)$
$= \displaystyle -\sum_1^n (-1)^k x^k \sigma_k(1, 2, \ldots, n) = \sum_1^n (-1)^{k + 1}x^k \sigma_k(1, 2, \ldots, n); \tag{20}$

we immediately see from (20) that the coefficient of $x^k$ in $p(x)$ is $(-1)^{k + 1} \sigma_k(1, 2, \ldots, n)$ for $1 \le k \le n$; that is, in the notation of our OP Leonardo Vannini,

$a_k = (-1)^{k + 1} \sigma_k(1, 2, \ldots, n), \; 1 \le k \le n, \tag{21}$

and of course,

$a_0 = a_k = 0, \; k > n. \tag{22}$

By virtue of (21), we can present some explicit formulas for some of the $a_k$:

$a_1 = \displaystyle (-1)^2 \sigma_1(1, 2, \ldots , n) = \sum_1^n k = \dfrac{n(n + 1)}{2}; \tag {23}$

$a_n = (-1)^{n + 1} \sigma_n(1, 2, \ldots , n) = (-1)^{n + 1} n!; \tag{24}$

if we introduce the $n$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)

$\displaystyle H_n = \sum_1^n \dfrac{1}{k}, \tag {25}$

we note that

$n! H_n = \sigma_{n - 1}(1, 2, \ldots, n), \tag{26}$

which leads to

$a_{n - 1} = (-1)^n \sigma_{n - 1}(1, 2, \ldots, n) = (-1)^n n! H_n; \tag{27}$

with a little more work we can also find an expression for $a_{n - 2}$ in terms of $H_n$, since

$\displaystyle H_n^2 = (\sum_1^n \dfrac{1}{k})^2 = \sum_1^n \dfrac{1}{k^2} + 2\sum_{k, l = 1;\; k < l}^{k, l = n} \dfrac{1}{kl}, \tag{28}$

so that

$\displaystyle \sum_{k, l = 1;\; k < l}^{k, l = n} \dfrac{1}{kl} = \dfrac{1}{2}(H_n^2 -  \sum_1^n \dfrac{1}{k^2}); \tag{29}$

also,

$\sigma_{n - 2}(1, 2, \ldots, n) = n!\displaystyle \sum_{k, l = 1;\; k < l}^{k, l = n} \dfrac{1}{kl}, \tag{30}$

and combining (29) and (30) allows us to write

$a_{n - 2} = (-1)^{n - 1} \sigma_{n - 2}(1, 2, \ldots, n) = \dfrac{(-1)^{n - 1}}{2}n!(H_n^2 -  \sum_1^n \dfrac{1}{k^2}). \tag{31}$

I think it's pretty obvious at this point that one can continue on in this vein, and derive a large number of variants on the formulas for the $a_k$, but I question what is really gained, at least at this point, by such an endeavor.  There seems to be no significant reduction in either algebraic or computational complexity evident in such an undertaking, so for the moment at least I shall let this answer lie as it is . . .